# How to run multiple karate feature files in parallel?

Tags: testing, automation, karate, parallel-testing

I have multiple feature file each containing multiple scenarios, I want to run scenarios in sequential order and features in parallel,

so i tried using

```
package com.api.automation;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner.Builder;

 

public class ParallelRunner {
    @Test
    public void executeKarateTest()
    {
        Builder aRunner = new Builder();
        aRunner.path("classpath:Package_A", "classpath:Package_B");
         aRunner.parallel(4);

    }}
```

as this runs both feature files and scenarios in parallel
I have used `@parallel=false` in each feature file to run scenarios in scequential order

but even the feature files also executing in series

|--com.api.automation
|         |-ParallelRunner.java
|
|--Package_A
|         |-A_1.feature
|         |-A_2.feature
|
|--Package_B
|         |-B_1.feature
|         |-B_2.feature

Comment: karate defaults to running scenarios in parallel. I don't understand what you mean that feature files are run in series. if you can follow this process, someone can look into it: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - but I will say that this is low priority, you are of course welcome to contribute code to karate to improve it